# Installing ckfinder on ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using ckfinder in my ckeditor for my Laravel project. But I can not see upload button inside ckeditor image plugin. This is the document I [follow](https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/)

```html
@extends('admin.main')
@section('head')
    {!! Html::script('https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/full-all/ckeditor.js') !!}
@endsection
@section('body')
    ...
    {!! Form::textarea('body', null, []); !!}
    ...
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[check this one](https://github.com/senocak/Laravel-CKEDITOR-CKFINDER-usage)

It should work, comment me down if you stil get any errors